# How does docker swarm handle volumes mounted on replicated services and How would one integrate this with S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, containers, docker-swarm, operations-orchestration

`Setup`: A docker swarm with one manager and one worker node (two virtual machines at play). The `docker-stack.yml` contains two services

- `primary`: [bitnami/postgresql](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/postgresql/) image setup as the master postgres server.

  - Has a local directory (`./docker/primary/data` on manager node) mounted to persist data from primary postgres service.
  - Only 1 instance will be running.
- `replica`: [bitnami/postgresql](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/postgresql/) image setup as the replicated postgres server.

  - Does not have any volume mounted. This means the replicated data is ephemeral and restarting the container would lead to data loss on `replica` service instances.
  - Has 5 instances running via `replicas: 5` under `deploy:` key of `docker-stack.yml`.
- This setup works and doing `select * from pg_stat_replication;` shows 5 wal recievers on `primary`.
- Both virtual machines within the swarm are running locally on my computer on debian. In
  a real production environment, these two machines would be two individual ec2 instances. I'm only running it locally to learn HA deployments.

`Goal`: Save the data for each replicated instances of 'replica' service to a separate directory (maybe locally on the worker node itself in a unique directory or on aws s3 bucket for backup; this should total to 5 unique backup's from each replicated instance of 'replica' service for the above setup).

`Problem`:

- If I mount a local volume on the `replica` service in the same way as I mounted for my `primary` service. I think this would lead to write races since each 'replica' instance of the service would try to write to the same folder and the local folder's aren't guaurrented to exist worker and manager nodes in the swam. How do you overcome this?
- If the above local backups work, how do you then take this local directory and back that up to aws s3 bucket?

`Research`: I've searched around this problem and came to a conclusion that swarm isn't really good at state-full replication and swarm is designed more for stateless replication of a given service.

- `docker-stack.yml`

```yml
version: "3.9"

# temporary env vars.
services:
  primary:
    image: "bitnami/postgresql:latest"
    environment:
      postgresql_username: "primary"
      postgresql_password: "password"
      postgresql_database: "lune"
      postgresql_replication_mode: "master"
      postgresql_replication_user: "replica"
      postgresql_replication_password: "password"
      postgresql_synchronous_commit_mode: "on"
      postgresql_num_synchronous_replicas: "1"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/primary/data:/bitnami/postgresql
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    networks:
      - backend
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
  replica:
    image: "bitnami/postgresql:latest"
    depends_on:
      - primary
    environment:
      postgresql_password: "password"
      postgresql_replication_mode: "slave"
      postgresql_replication_user: "replica"
      postgresql_replication_password: "password"
      postgresql_master_host: "primary"
      postgresql_master_port_number: "5432"
    ports:
      - 5433:5432
    networks:
      - backend
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure

networks:
  backend:
```